# How to change the color of keywords from android.widget?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have a small problem I can't solve. I'm using Eclipse IDE and I'm developing my first Android application. I see that some of the Java keywords like public, boolean, static and many others are different colour (purple) than the usual black text. But the types like EditText from android.widget is as same colour as the other text. So my question is: How can I change that colour? I saw in Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts that there are some options related to my problem but I don't know which colour pointing to my problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of Classes (via Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring, then Java -> Classes) but this will apply to *all* classes (including your own).

AFAIK this cannot be done for individual classes or packages.